# Define union type from typed list

Tags: typescript

If I have a list, like `const list: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, how do I create a union type that only allows me to have the values `'a', 'b', 'c'`?

I am aware that you can achieve this by doing:

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type allowedValues = typeof list[number]
```

But you cannot type `list` this way (e.g. with the type `string[]`); TypeScript complains that `list` is read-only. Is there a way of creating a type that only allows values of list whilst still being able to type list arbitrarily?

Comment: Once you have `string[]` you've already lost the information about _which_ strings.

Comment: satisfies keyword.

Comment: If this is right i'm gonna write an answer. Like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgsiAMgSwM7CgXigJwgQwBMB7AOwBsQpSBXAWwCMIcBtAXQCgOBjM9KAB5YoLAOT5RAGiiiGUmd1Fso+VFF6l+qfMDQAzZBDXwkaYDz4Yq2FgAZJARkkAmZavWWo23agNHYCCjoQA

Comment: Do you __only__ want the values `["a", "b", "c"]` or could you allow `["a", "a", "b", "c"]`?

Answer (score 0):

I often use this method:

```js
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type ListType = typeof list;
type AllowedValues = ListType[number];

const definedVariable:AllowedValues[] = ["a"]; // ok
```

The reason being that if you had data that needed to be sorted into the order dictated by the order of the values in `list`, then you could still make use of it like so:

```js
someArrOfAllowedValues.sort(
    (a, b) => allBetTypes.indexOf(a) - allBetTypes.indexOf(b)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to compute such a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) is by annotating your variable using [Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) in the array. There simply is no way for the compiler to tell your array contains `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` when you declared it with a *wider* type of `string[]`.

```
const list: ["a", "b", "c"] = ["a", "b", "c"];
type AllowedValues = (typeof list)[number];
// type AllowedValues = "a" | "b" | "c"
```

The most straight forward way to get back to an *arbitrary* type `string[]` is [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```
(list as string[]).push("d");
```

---

The problem with [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) is that TypeScript will force you to assert to `unknown` first. So you'll have to do this:

```
(list as unknown as string[]).push("d");
```